# I have the latest pip version but during pandas and Jupyter install it "sees" an old one

Tags: upgrade, python, python3, pip

Ι have to point out that I am a newbie in Linux and setting up python so I may have complicated things in my system.

I tried installing Rodeo python IDE and during start up a message appeared informing me that I don't have pandas and Jupyter although I had them installed. I want to use Python 3. After the message I tried installing Jupyter and Pandas manually with pip3, they were installed but I got the following message:

"You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command."

But if I type:

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ilias/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ilias/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

In addition when checking python versions:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

And finally the commands:

```
$ which python
/home/ilias/anaconda3/bin/python

$ which pip
/home/ilias/anaconda3/bin/pip

$ which -a python
/home/ilias/anaconda3/bin/python
/home/ilias/miniconda2/bin/python
/home/ilias/anaconda2/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

$ whic -a pip
/home/ilias/anaconda3/bin/pip
/home/ilias/miniconda2/bin/pip
/home/ilias/anaconda2/bin/pip
/home/ilias/.local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

So any ideas? I'm pretty sure I screwd something up...

Comment: First of all `python --version` should return `python 2.x.x` but for you returns `3.x.x`, Ubuntu uses python 2 for different purposes, I guess by installing `Anaconda` you somehow broke something, remove `anaconda`, reinstall `python 2`, run `pip install --upgrade pip --user` and `pip3 install --upgrade pip --user`.

Comment: @Ravexina It's not necessarily a problem for python point to python3 and my install of anaconda is also like this. It is curious that pip3 points to a different version than pip, though. Did you try just installing jupyter with pip?